# running a series of scripts on a series of opened tabs

Tags: javascript, tabs, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, onsubmit

I am making an experimental addon that will search for a single term on several different art sites at once.

### The addon works by doing the following:

1. Opens a window asking for user input (the term to search for)
2. Stores this input
3. Starts a crude loop process
4. The loop opens the first tab in the list
5. The loop attaches runs the first script in the list
   (these scripts pretty much all work the same way)
6. This script is attached as a worker to the tab
7. The script enters the term into a search box in the tab then submits it
8. The submit triggers the worker to be destroyed
9. Steps 4-8 repeat until the list runs out of tabs to open
   Note: the number of these steps have nothing to do with the step numbers in the code

### Main.js

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var journal_entry = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
  contentURL: data.url("DeltaLogPanel.html"),
  contentScriptFile: data.url("get-text.js")
});
// Creates the button
require("sdk/ui/button/action").ActionButton({
  id: "make-post",
  label: "Make post",
  icon: {
    "16": "./icon-16.png",
    "32": "./icon-32.png",
    "64": "./icon-64.png"
  },
  onClick: handleClick
});
var count = 0;
function handleClick(state) {
  journal_entry.show();
}
journal_entry.once("show", function() {
  journal_entry.port.emit("show");
});
function doit() {
    console.log("Step 1, loop "+ count +" started!");;
    if(count < sites.urls.length)
    {
        TabIt(count);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("loop ended");
    }
}
function TabIt(x) {
    console.log("Step 2, tab "+ count +" is opening!");
   tabs.open(sites.urls[count]);
    handleTab(count);
}
//this is our cargo. There's normally more stuff in it
var Cargo = {
    Title: ""
};
var sites = {
urls: ["https://www.sofurry.com/", "https://inkbunny.net/search.php", "http://www.furaffinity.net/search/", "https://www.weasyl.com/search", "http://www.deviantart.com/"],
scripts: ["searchSF.js", "searchIB.js", "searchFA.js", "searchWS.js", "searchDA.js"]
};
function handleTab(X) 
{
    console.log("Step 3, tab  "+ count +" is processing!");
//I tried tabs.on('load'.. and that didn't fix the problem
    tabs.on('ready', function RunPostScript(tab) 
    {
        console.log("The tab is ready");
        worker = tab.attach(
        {
              contentScriptFile: sites.scripts[X],
              contentScriptOptions: 
              {
                Cargo
              }
        });
        worker.port.once("myMessage", function handleMyMessage() 
        {
            console.log("Step 4, search "+ count +" is shuttin down!");
            //tab.close();
            worker.destroy();
        });
        tabs.removeListener("ready", RunPostScript);
    console.log("Step 5, search "+ count +" should be finished!");
    count=count+1;
    console.log("Ready to do it again?");
    doit();
    });
}
journal_entry.port.once("cargo-shipping", function (cargo) {
    Cargo.Title = cargo.title;
    console.log("title: " + Cargo.Title);
    //All data from panel should be imported. So panel is now hidden
    journal_entry.hide();
    //this starts the tab opening process
    TabIt(count);
});
```

### DeltaLogPanel.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <!-- <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="DeltaLogPanel.css"/> -->
        <style>
            #MainPanel 
            {
            width: 180px;
            height:180px;
            background-color: #ACA1A1;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body id="MainPanel">
        <div id="simpleOptions">
            <textarea id="titleBox" placeholder="Title" rows="1"></textarea>
            <button type="button" id="publishButton">Publish</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### get-text.js

```
var titleArea = document.getElementById("titleBox");
var finalButton = document.getElementById("publishButton");

//this defines the cargo on the button press then ships it.
finalButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Remove the newline.
    var cargo = {
        title: ""
    };
    cargo.title = titleArea.value;
    self.port.emit("cargo-shipping", cargo);
    titleArea.value = "";
}, false);

//focusses on title box when button is pressed
self.port.on("show", function onShow() {
  titleArea.focus();
});
```

### searchFA.js

```
document.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
console.log("Unloading now");
self.port.emit("myMessage");
}, false);
//puts words in the input box
var titlePort = function(x){
    var FAzA = document.querySelector("form#search-form fieldset input#q");
    FAzA.value = x;
};
//hits the submit button
var ShipIt = function(){
document.querySelector("form#search-form").submit();
};
var Finalize = function(){
titlePort(self.options.Cargo.Title);
ShipIt();
};
Finalize();
```

### searchIB.js

```
document.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
console.log("Unloading now");
self.port.emit("myMessage");
}, false);
//puts words in the input box
var titlePort = function(x){
    var IBzA = document.querySelector("#text");
    IBzA.value = x;
};
//hits the submit button
var ShipIt = function(){
    var x = document.querySelector("body > form:nth-child(12)");
    var y =document.querySelector("body > form:nth-child(9)");
    if (x !==null || y !==null)
    {
        if (x !== null) 
        {
            x.submit();
        }
        else 
        {
            y.submit();
        }
    }
};
var Finalize = function(){
titlePort(self.options.Cargo.Title);
ShipIt();
};
Finalize();
```

### searchSF.js

```
document.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
console.log("Unloading now");
self.port.emit("myMessage");
}, false);
//puts words in the input box
var titlePort = function(x){
    var SFzA = document.querySelector("#headersearch");
    SFzA.value = x;
};
//hits the submit button
var ShipIt = function(){
document.querySelector(".topbar-nav > form:nth-child(3)").submit();
};
var Finalize = function(){
titlePort(self.options.Cargo.Title);
ShipIt();
};
Finalize();
```

### searchWS.js

```
document.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
console.log("Unloading now");
self.port.emit("myMessage");
}, false);
//puts words in the input box
var titlePort = function(x){
    var WSzA = document.querySelector("form#search-backup-search input");
    WSzA.value = x;
};
//hits the submit button
var ShipIt = function(){
document.querySelector("form#search-backup-search").submit();
};
var Finalize = function(){
titlePort(self.options.Cargo.Title);
ShipIt();
};
Finalize();
```

### searchDA.js

```
document.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
console.log("Unloading now");
self.port.emit("myMessage");
}, false);
//puts words in the input box
var titlePort = function(x){
    var DAzA = document.querySelector("input.gmbutton2");
    DAzA.value = x;
};
//hits the submit button
var ShipIt = function(){
document.querySelector("#search7").submit();
};
var Finalize = function(){
titlePort(self.options.Cargo.Title);
ShipIt();
};
Finalize();
```

### What does work

It stores the user input.
The addon loads all the tabs in the series perfectly. 
The first script runs smoothly on the first tab.
When tested separately, each of the scripts runs the search result like they should.

### The problem

When everything is finished, not all the tabs display the search results. Several of the search boxes are left blank as if the scripts never ran on those tabs. 
The script of the first tab always works, but the scripts on the rest of the tabs have a random chance of not working.
I noticed the `console.log("Step 4, search "+ count +" is shuttin down!");` is never executed. I think this means the worker is never destroyed.
That might be causing these issues.
The worker for each script should be destroyed after the script runs the following: `self.port.emit("myMessage");`
This little segment of code is at the top of every script. But I think the submit process happens too fast for the event listener to be triggered.

### Error message

I am getting the following error message for each of the scripts that do not work:

```
    Object
- _errorType = TypeError
- message = FAzA is null
- fileName = resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource:/
/gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/sandbox.js -> resource://jid1-tbpzbqttcoeaag-at
-jetpack/my-addon/data/searchFA.js
- lineNumber = 8
- stack = titlePort@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> res
ource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/sandbox.js -> resource://jid1-     tbpzbqttco
eaag-at-jetpack/my-  addon/data/searchFA.js:8:2|Finalize@resource://gre/modules/co
 mmonjs/toolkit/loader.js ->    resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/sandbox.j
s -> resource://jid1-tbpzbqttcoeaag-at-jetpack/my-  addon/data/searchFA.js:15:1|@r
esource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js ->   resource://gre/modules/commo
njs/sdk/loader/sandbox.js -> resource://jid1-tbpzbqttcoeaag-at-jetpack/my-  addon/
data/searchFA.js:18:1|
- name = TypeError
```

If only one tab/script is run, this error never happens. This is true for every tab/script combination. So I know they should all work.

### My Question to you

How can I destroy the worker of each script after the script runs the submit function?

Comment: This isn't much help, but I would put a whole lot more of `console.log()` around the problematic area to get a better idea of what is failing. Does the browser console say nothing regarding errors/warnings (assuming javascript.options.showInConsole is set) ?

Comment: Excellent work here, but there is an addon that already does find in all tabs: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/findbar-tweak/

Comment: @yatg
This is an experimental addon. I'm using this concept to build a more complex addon that will allow crossposting journals across all of these websites. 
I need the practice and the understanding to build up to this.

Comment: @spenibus I already had a lot more `console.log()` in the code around the area. It didn't tell me more than what I already suspected about the problem. I cut most of them out to shorten the code I pasted here.

But I did get a few perplexing errors. The strangest one is too long for this comment box, should I add it to the end of the post?

Comment: Being aware of all errors/warnings might likely help.

Comment: Hmm, what if you replace all instances of `Finalize();` with `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", Finalize);` ? This feels like the answer but I don't want to run the victory lap early.

Comment: I tried that and added a `console.log()` into the finalize function for debugging. For some reason the finalize function was never triggered. Maybe the content loads before the tab attaches a worker to it.

Comment: Can you "export" the addon so I could install it ?

Comment: I will absolutely do that. But I've never gotten this far making an addon. Could you link me to a page on how to export the addon? You've been a big help so far.

Comment: I don't use the SDK to build addons but I suppose this is it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_started#Packaging_the_add-on

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/download/8n0sdasrcagpp2v/my-addon.zip

Comment: @FergusWyrm I haven't forgotten about this, I've just been busy. You can drop me an email via my site so we can avoid a longer comment chain.

Answer (score 1):

Your error:

> FAzA is null

indicates that the element was not found in the page when using `querySelector()`.

The problem is mostly here:

```
tabs.on('ready', function RunPostScript(tab) {...});
```

This monitors all the tabs and creates a race condition when submitting a search. The following happens:

1. attach ready event listener to tabs waiting for site A
2. open site A
3. page A fires ready event, attach script A to site A
4. remove ready event listener
5. increment count
6. end of loop, call next tab
7. attach ready event listener to tabs waiting for site B
8. meanwhile, site A submits the search, it loads the result page and fires a ready event
9. attach script B to site A
10. site A is now processed as site B, script B can't find the search input, outputs error
11. remove ready event listener
12. increment count
13. end of loop, call next tab
14. attach ready event listener to tabs waiting for site C
15. etc

You should monitor events at the tab level. Use `once()` so you don't have to remove the listener. Something like this:

```
function TabIt(x) {
    tabs.open({
        url:sites.urls[x],
        onOpen: function(x, tab) {
            // fire once
            // count is available in this scope, no need to setup as arg again
            tab.once('ready', function readyStuff(tab) {
                tab.attach({
                    contentScriptFile: sites.scripts[x],
                    contentScriptOptions:{Cargo}
                });
            });
        }
    });
    ++count;
    doit();
}
```

You also keep using `count` instead of `x`, while it's possible to do so, it would require binding the value because of the scope in which `count` exists. But since you have `x`, just use it.

I also advised in comments to use `DOMContentLoaded` in attached scripts. After reading more on script attachment to tabs, that was bad advice.

Your code could be vastly optimized but let's do one thing at a time.

Comment: For those interested in the fully optimized scripts (fixed by spenibus of course) you can download them [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/fs3ec550xkmfwqw/searcher.zip).

Answer (score 0):

```
const { getMostRecentBrowserWindow } = require('sdk/window/utils');
var aDOMWindow = getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
if (aDOMWindow.gBrowser && aDOMWindow.gBrowser.tabContainer) {
    var tabs = aDOMWindow.gBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes;
        for (var i=0; i<tabs.length; i++) {
            // tabs[i].contentWindow.wrappedJSObject.... // not e10s friendly, so to tabs[i].messageManager or something like that
       }
}
```

here is frame scripts which are absolutely easy:
https://github.com/mdn/e10s-example-addons/tree/master/run-script-in-all-pages

Comment: This just runs the script on every page without being prompted by the user to start running. For my purposes, I need the addon to open several tabs to preselected URLs and have a specific script run on each of them. After this happens, the addon no longer needs to be running. Is there a way to implement your solution so it can do this?

Comment: Yes @FergusWyrm its very easily modifiable, every time you open a tab with `gBrowser.loadOneTab(..)`  just do `var tab = gBorwser.loadOneTab(..)` and then to that `tab` var do the same as you would in the above example in the for loop. I'm not sure of the pure sdk solution however, like i dont know how to destory page workers. So don't accept my solution hopefully some sdk devuser will reply.